# How to return translation in toString Method in Entity

Tags: symfony

I have a entity and a entity translation, both look like this.

```
class Question
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getId();
        /** @todo
         Return translated title instead of id
        **/
    }
}

class QuestionTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $explanation;}
}
```

I would like to return in my "__toString" Method the translated title of this entity, but how can i access the translated title from "QuestionTranslation"?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using KNP translatable, so you can do it like this:

```
public function __toString() {
    if( $title = $this->translate()->getTitle() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    // if no translation has been added, return empty string instead.
    return '';
}
```

I will strongly suggest you to set this piece of code in its own method in your entity, instead of `__toString()`. Afterwards, you do something like this:

```
print $entity->getTitle(); // which call for the translated title.
```

You can apply this practice for multiple translated field, instead of relying on `__toString`.